# Usage of Ternary Operators

Tags: javascript, operators, ternary

I'm completely in the dark with this one.

"Generate a random number between 0 and 99 and assign it to the luck variable.

Write a condition that should check if Mr. Pink's luck is greater than 90. If so, the conditional statement should assign 'Mr. Purple'  to alias. Otherwise, it should assign 'Mr. Pink'.

Print the alias value to the console."

So far i have an alias that checks if the luck factor is greater than 90 but i'm lost how to return Mr. Purple and if the value is less than 90 to return Mr. Pink. I've tried to put the value in the alias var but without result.

My questions in here are do i need to make more var statements and i think that i need also if statements. Any tips and hints are more than welcome.

The little code i have at this moment

```
var luck=(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 99));
var alias= luck >=90;
```

Comment: please check link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: var alias = luck >= 90 ? 'Mr. Purple' : 'Mr. Pink';

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with ternary operators in the following way:

```
var luck = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 99));
var alias = luck >= 90 ? "Mr. Purple" : "Mr. Pink";
```

What this says is:

1. If the luck is over 90 - assign the string "Mr.Purple"
2. If the luck is not equal to or over 90 - assign the string "Mr. Pink"

So basically, the bit after the `?` is what to assign when it's true, and the bit after the `:` is what to assign when it's false. Here you can read more about ternary operators in Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator